# Do I need to book a taxi before arriving at Paris La Défense?

Tags: bookings, paris, taxis

Next Thursday near 9 AM, I might have to take a cab from La Défense metro station to go to a district which is outside the subway zone.

According to [this PDF file](http://www.ladefense.fr/sites/default/files/pdf/guide-info-trafic.pdf) (in French) about Paris La Défense (page 4) and [this map](http://www.coeurdefense.com/fr-FR/pratique/plan-d-acces/), there is a taxi station at La Défense not far from the metro station.

Google Street View [shows the station](https://www.google.fr/maps/@48.893454,2.238703,3a,43.2y,229.02h,85.22t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1soPUX1ejNWRu6CA-U0S7C6A!2e0!3e5!6m1!1e1), and there are five taxi cabs waiting, but there are only one cab from [another point of view](https://www.google.fr/maps/@48.893434,2.238409,3a,50.4y,137.19h,74.89t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sJV8x2Nf6p3wf8XQSg-_v4g!2e0!3e5!6m1!1e1). [The other lane](https://www.google.fr/maps/@48.893526,2.238167,3a,26.1y,269.89h,85.18t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1skBXcc0ftSFCaA9KXLgPG3g!2e0!3e5!6m1!1e1) is empty. This is scary.

Are there cabs available all the time there, or do I have to book a taxi before arriving at La Défense? If I have to book it, is it better to do it a few minutes before arriving, or should I do it the day before my trip?

---

After being at La Défense for five consecutive times near 9 AM and 9:30 AM, I confirm that there were *always* a lot of cabs available (always at least five, often more). I believe that this was also the case near 4 PM. Of course, the situation may be different on weekends.

Comment: What time of day? During working and rush hours at La Defense the cab ranks are well served, but after everyone goes home it's a lot more sparse.

Comment: @GayotFow: near 9 AM, so most people will *arrive* at La Défense, not leave it.

Comment: 9AM in the morning is fine.  You can expect no problems getting a taxi.

Comment: @MainMa You can answer your own question with that information, rather than editing this post. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La Défense is predominantly a business area, although it does attract a fairly large number of tourists due to many of the buildings in the area, as well as the fact that it's the end of the Metro line.

Ease of finding a taxi will depend on the time of day and day of week.  In general you should not have any issues, however there's likely times of the week when you may have some trouble, such as early in the day, especially on a weekend.

Thankfully there's an easy solution. Very close to the Defense station are two hotels - the Sofitel next to the Metro station, and the Renaissance a very short walk away.  Both of these should have taxis available most of the day, or will be able to arrange one for you if they don't.

(Ironically on my first ever trip to France I was headed to the Renaissance and my taxi driver got lost finding it!  I think we drove around the "loop" 3 or 4 times before he finally managed to find the right exit!)

Comment: So you got ripped off on your first trip to France?

Comment: Nope.  Driver didn't charge me for the part of the trip where we were lost!

Comment: Oh, that's rare, and cool.

Answer (score 8):

No, cabs at this location work like everywhere else in terms of demand, I would not rely on Google street view as your guide.  There are always cabs available at that location.  You may have to wait a few minutes during an off peak time, but my experiences have always been good.

Comment: Still, it is probably better to have the phone number of a taxi company, just in case.